# Pandas filter on categorical intervals

Tags: python, pandas

I create a dataframe and categorize one column as intervals :

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'col': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df_test['cat']= pd.cut(df_test['col'],[-1.,0.,3.,10.])
df_test

        col     cat
    0   0   (-1.0, 0.0]
    1   1   (0.0, 3.0]
    2   2   (0.0, 3.0]
    3   3   (0.0, 3.0]
    4   4   (3.0, 10.0]
    5   5   (3.0, 10.0]
    6   6   (3.0, 10.0]
```

Now I want to filter this dataframe using the cat column :

```
df_test[df_test['cat'] == pd.Interval(left=1., right=2.)]

    col     cat
1   1   (0.0, 3.0]
2   2   (0.0, 3.0]
3   3   (0.0, 3.0]
```

How come that checking equality with (1., 2.] yields this result ? I was expecting to get an empty result as that interval doesn't exist in the dataframe.

Am I supposed to filter using a different method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For exact matching is possible use hack solution - convert both to strings:

```
a = df_test[df_test['cat'].astype(str) == str(pd.Interval(left=1., right=2.))]
```

Or use `apply`:

```
a = df_test[df_test['cat'].apply(lambda x: x == pd.Interval(left=1., right=2.))]
print (a)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col, cat]
Index: []
```

More information why this is implemented for check membership is [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/19353)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why is it working with the apply ? What is the difference with what I tried ?

Comment: @Istopopoki - In my opinion here pandas developers decide `==` test all values in Interval or it is bug. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is working, the syntax means right now that he filters everything, which intervall is in `(1, 2)`, so in your case 0.0 until 3.0 has 1-2 inside, so he gives back a true, if you try:
`df_test[df_test['cat'] == pd.Interval(left=10, right=20)]`
you will get an empty datframe

If you want to see an excact matching, maybe it is better to split the intervall?

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension provides the result you expect:

```
[i == pd.Interval(1,2) for i in df['cat']]
```

Output:

```
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```